# Stream audio and video

Tags: audio, streaming-video, streaming

recently I bought a Raspberry Pi2 and Raspberry camera. I had successfully streamed video with `mjpgstreamer`.
now I want stream video and audio with it. I mean I seek for a solution to stream video and audio integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/). It supports Audio & Video Live streaming to any browser with WebRTC. It also supports MJPEG over HTTP, so it could eventually replace mjpegstreamer.

Comment: thanks,that worked fine. now i use UV4L to stream from a Raspberry to another Raspberry. I just want design a gui for the second one, can you help me with that?